# Auto Scroll with the JLabel containing an image

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel

There's something I want to try but I've no idea how to go about this and not sure if it's at all possible.

I've got a JPanel of JLabels using a GridLayout.  This JPanel is then added to a JScrollPane.

One if the JLabels has an image in it.  That image is supposed to show me where the character in the program is.  I just a JLabal so I can get it's position.  So basically when I want to move the character, I remove the image from the current JLabel and add it onto the next JLabel.  I understand this is possibly the worst approach ever but I am new, all I know is Java and I've got a deadline and didn't think to learn Game Development in Java.

Anyway, since I'm using a JScrollPane, I would like the program to automatically scroll when the JLabel with the image cannot be seen anymore.  Therefore as the character is moving, the JSCrollPane is scrolling, so I don't have to scroll to it.  It does it for me.  So like a camera watching where it's going.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. It is never a good idea to go beyond your ability; stick at the edge of your ability and do the best project you already know you can do. Check if the character is visible (less than the furthest visible JLabel), and scroll if necessary. Still, you can't build muscle by benching 200 lbs more than you can handle; you build it by benching what you can handle a couple hundred times.

Comment: Hi Aarowaim,  thank you for your kind advice, I really appreciate it.  And you're right I don't know too much.  However it's not a homework assignment, it's actually a development project for my work placement.  I want to show what I can do but it's not looking good.  I've got A LOT to learn.

But thank you :))

Comment: Haha, I see. If you need help figuring out if your character is visible, then post some code and show what you've tried; I'm sure we can help, as you seem to know the basics already. Do you think it'd be easier to work with actual graphics instead of hacking together a swing GUI? Maybe on the side, fiddle around with overloading a frame's `public void paint(Graphics g)`, but don't toss out your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand this is possibly the worst approach ever

You will get really terrible movement since the character will jump many pixels at one time (depending on the size of your image).

> Therefore as the character is moving, the JSCrollPane is scrolling, so I don't have to scroll to it.

After you add the Icon to a different label you can use the `scrollRectToVisible(..)` method of the label. You will need to make the Rectangle size equal to the size of the scrollpanes viewport to force the viewport to scroll every time. So you will need to calculate the x/y position to make sure the label stays centered in the viewport.

Comment: You're right about the movement, sometimes the image changes, other times it doesn't.  
Thank you I will try the scrollRectToVisible(..) method :)